# How to share Chrome's bookmarks between computers without a Google-Account?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, bookmarks

How can I share/sync my bookmarks in Chrome between several other computers?
I'm not a fan of synchronizing them via a google account, so I'm looking for a way to share/sync the bookmarks without a google account.

Is that possible? Are the bookmarks stored in some kind of file that I could just copy to the other computers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some like [Xmarks](http://download.xmarks.com/download/all).

Comment: Awesome. I'm syncing between 3 computers and it works like a charm

Answer (score 3):

The Bookmarks are stored in this directory: `%APPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` on my machine, and should be similar on yours.  There are 2 files, `bookmarks` and `bookmarks.bak`

Comment: The user profile and appdata paths have changed between Windows releases. In Win7, they are `UserProfile`=`%SystemDrive%\Users` and `AppData`=`%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming`.

Answer (score 2):

Bookmarkmanagement -> Organize ->Import/Export bookmarks options if you can be bothered with copying files.